# Iferror return 0 for worksheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have a pretty extensive workbook with thousands of references. My boss would like me to make a consolidated list of GP, Profit, Expenses for all items but in doing so easily I would need to remove all "#N/A" cells without compromising the integrity of such cell formulas. AKA I don't just want to clear the cells that return "#N/A"s but rather start each formula with an =IFERROR(*cell*,0). Can someone please help me write a VBA code that will take each cell on a selected WORKSHEET and insert an IFERROR return "0"? It is important that the VBA only works on selected worksheets since I don't want my whole workbook overwrited with IFERROR statements.

Comment: You need to write a one-time macro that will edit all formulas in a given specified range and wrap it with `IFERROR([original-formula],"0")` - if you're stuck on a *specific* problem doing that, you need to post the relevant code and explain what the problem is. As it stands this question is too broad for this site, you're essentially asking us to give you working code, which is outside the scope of this site.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub WrapIFERROR()
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        Cell.Formula = "=IFERROR(" & Mid(Cell.Formula, 2) & ",0)"
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Better if you first get all cells which contain formulas using `SpecialCells`. `Used Range` can be huge.

Comment: I'd drop `.UsedRange` altogether now, as unreliable. And maybe you should test that the cell doesn't start with "=IFERROR".